# Facebook-Prophet: Overflow error when fitting

Tags: facebook-prophet

I wanted to practice with prophet so I decided to download the "Yearly mean total sunspot number [1700 - now]" data from this place

http://www.sidc.be/silso/datafiles#total.

This is my code so far

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from fbprophet import Prophet
from fbprophet.plot import plot_plotly
import plotly.offline as py
import datetime

py.init_notebook_mode()

plt.style.use('classic')

df = pd.read_csv('SN_y_tot_V2.0.csv',delimiter=';', names = ['ds', 'y','C3', 'C4', 'C5'])


df = df.drop(columns=['C3', 'C4', 'C5'])

df.plot(x="ds", style='-',figsize=(10,5))
plt.xlabel('year',fontsize=15);plt.ylabel('mean number of sunspots',fontsize=15)
plt.xticks(np.arange(1701.5, 2018.5,40))
plt.ylim(-2,300);plt.xlim(1700,2020)
plt.legend()df['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(df.ds, format='%Y')


df['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(df.ds, format='%Y')

m = Prophet(yearly_seasonality=True)
```

Everything looks good so far and df['ds'] is in date time format.

However when I execute

`m.fit(df)`

I get the following error

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-a8e399fdfab2> in <module>()
----> 1 m.fit(df)

/anaconda2/envs/mde/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fbprophet/forecaster.py in fit(self, df, **kwargs)
   1055         self.history_dates = pd.to_datetime(df['ds']).sort_values()
   1056 
-> 1057         history = self.setup_dataframe(history, initialize_scales=True)
   1058         self.history = history
   1059         self.set_auto_seasonalities()

/anaconda2/envs/mde/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fbprophet/forecaster.py in setup_dataframe(self, df, initialize_scales)
    286             df['cap_scaled'] = (df['cap'] - df['floor']) / self.y_scale
    287 
--> 288         df['t'] = (df['ds'] - self.start) / self.t_scale
    289         if 'y' in df:
    290             df['y_scaled'] = (df['y'] - df['floor']) / self.y_scale

/anaconda2/envs/mde/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py in wrapper(left, right)
    990             # test_dt64_series_add_intlike, which the index dispatching handles
    991             # specifically.
--> 992             result = dispatch_to_index_op(op, left, right, pd.DatetimeIndex)
    993             return construct_result(
    994                 left, result, index=left.index, name=res_name, dtype=result.dtype

/anaconda2/envs/mde/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py in dispatch_to_index_op(op, left, right, index_class)
    628         left_idx = left_idx._shallow_copy(freq=None)
    629     try:
--> 630         result = op(left_idx, right)
    631     except NullFrequencyError:
    632         # DatetimeIndex and TimedeltaIndex with freq == None raise ValueError

/anaconda2/envs/mde/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimelike.py in __sub__(self, other)
    521         def __sub__(self, other):
    522             # dispatch to ExtensionArray implementation
--> 523             result = self._data.__sub__(maybe_unwrap_index(other))
    524             return wrap_arithmetic_op(self, other, result)
    525 

/anaconda2/envs/mde/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimelike.py in __sub__(self, other)
   1278             result = self._add_offset(-other)
   1279         elif isinstance(other, (datetime, np.datetime64)):
-> 1280             result = self._sub_datetimelike_scalar(other)
   1281         elif lib.is_integer(other):
   1282             # This check must come after the check for np.timedelta64

/anaconda2/envs/mde/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py in _sub_datetimelike_scalar(self, other)
    856 
    857         i8 = self.asi8
--> 858         result = checked_add_with_arr(i8, -other.value, arr_mask=self._isnan)
    859         result = self._maybe_mask_results(result)
    860         return result.view("timedelta64[ns]")

/anaconda2/envs/mde/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py in checked_add_with_arr(arr, b, arr_mask, b_mask)
   1006 
   1007     if to_raise:
-> 1008         raise OverflowError("Overflow in int64 addition")
   1009     return arr + b
   1010 

OverflowError: Overflow in int64 addition```

I understand that there's an issue with 'ds', but I am not sure whether there is something wring with the column's format or an open issue.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? I have checked some issues in github, but they haven't been of much help in this case.


Thanks
````

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to fix the issue, but how to avoid the error.

I got the same error, and manage to get rid of the error when I reduce the number of data that is coming in OR when I reduce the horizon span of the forecast.

For example, I limit my training data to only start since 1825 meanwhile I have data from the year of 1700s. I also tried to limit my forecast days from 10 years forecast to only 1 year. Both managed to get rid of the error.

My guess this problem has something to do with how the ARIMA is implemented inside the Prophet itself which in some cases the number is just to huge to be managed by int64 and become overflow.

Comment: I had forgotten about this question! 
Thanks, I will give it a try, out of curiosity.